# Can you add basic text formatting (bold, italic) in Yammer posts?

Tags: formatting, text-formatting, yammer

When writing a post (or a comment on a post) in Yammer, is there any way to add basic text formatting such as **bold** or *italic* text?

[image: Screenshot of Yammer's "write comment" text field]

Comment: There isn't anything in their documentation about it. So it looks like no--unless someone knows of undocumented tricks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There used to be a feature request in their moderated feedback forum (the forum has since been closed down, maybe after Microsoft purchase).

There are also some hints in the new support forum that this feature is still not implemented:

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/176/t/411396?ss=74658578-9abc-4885-842c-ca72c4abf31f

Comment: The feature request status is *declined*, as of Mar 6, 2012. So I guess we  will **not** have any kind of formatting in Yammer any time soon.

Comment: The link is actually broken now.

Comment: There is now a user voice for Yammer (as is the case with many O365 products).

In particular there is a User Voice Item on support for Markdown in Yammer that is marked as "Considering" at the time of this comment.

https://yammer.uservoice.com/forums/399627-yammer/suggestions/18573466-markdown

Answer (score 5):

You can use Yammer notes, which provide formatting, such as bolding, italics, headings and bullets.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the recent update from Yammer:

> Beginning March 15, 2019, we are rolling out rich text formatting for
>   Yammer posts. This includes bold, italic, links, bullets, and numbered
>   lists.
>
> Composing messages with rich text formatting is only available on the
>   web client and Yammer desktop.
>
> Mobile Yammer apps will display formatted messages, but users can't
>   edit those messages or format new messages from the mobile device.
>
> Composing and viewing formatted messages won't be available
>   immediately on the Yammer SharePoint web part or Yammer tab in Teams.
>   This functionality will be added later in 2019.

Find the rest of the article [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/get-started-with-yammer/rich-text-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

In Yammer groups, if you post an "***Announcement***" you get the option to give it some basic formatting, but if you post an "***Update***" then it's in unformatted text.  So, yes, there is a way to do it after all.

Answer (score 1):

Only admins can post announcements; and replies to announcements cannot be formatted. You can also format text in Word documents and upload them to Yammer; not quite the same thing though is it?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen formatted text in replies in Yammer, these were made by sending email.  Never managed to get it to work myself.

Comment: Can you add more information about how to do that?

Comment: It appears that top-level posts must be plain text, but follow-up comments can use text formatting if you submit the comments through email.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Yammer page on UserVoice.com,

> **WE PLAN TO BUILD THIS**
> *Emma Beede (Admin, Yammer) responded  ·  Mar 10, 2017*
>
> We’re currently looking to learn about text formatting in Yammer and your
> other work tools. Please fill out the following survey to help us design
> this feature request: [bit.ly/2m4Zj7I](http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3411864/RTF)

https://yammer.uservoice.com/forums/399627-yammer/suggestions/15612084-support-rich-text-formatting-in-yammer-posts

Sorry if this directly address the original question but I wanted readers to know that Microsoft is planning to add this feature (as of 2017).

If you aren't familiar with UserVoice, it is a place to propose ideas for an application and vote on them.  Posts with lots of votes tend to get the attention of the vendor.  Microsoft uses this site for Yammer, Visual Studio, and their Office products.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to format posts in Yammer! As shown in the picture you can add bold and italic text, link text and ad bullet points and numbered lists.

[image: Yammer formatting menu]